# How to pass Java List to Python function using Jython?

Tags: java, python, jython

I am trying to pass Java arraylist to Python function. I am getting below error

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/GEO_DM] threw exception [Cant instantiate class: com.ppts.bean.TriggerLawSocietyServiceBean.] with root cause
>       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'ofArrayType' must be compatible with existing array type of [Lorg.python.core.PyObject;    see java.lang.Class.getName().

Please see my java code below:

```
 PythonInterpreter interpreter=new PythonInterpreter(); 
    PyList pyList=new PyList(new ArrayList<>());
    interpreter.execfile(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/ppts/propertiesfiles/sample_return_script.py"));
    PyObject function=interpreter.get("returnSample");
    PyObject result=function.__call__(new PyInteger(1),pyList,new PyDictionary());
    progress=(int) result.__tojava__(Integer.class);
```

Please see my python code:

```
def returnSample(var, list, dict):
    print(var)
    b=1
    flag=True
    print(list[0])
    print(dict.keys())
    return b
```

Please dont see the logics done in python. 
Just help me to pass the Arraylist to that python function

Comment: How can we reproduce that error? I think you should provide a [mcve].

Comment: Hi, while passing the Arraylist to python function, I am getting this error.
function.__call__(new PyInteger(1),pyList,new PyDictionary()); Please check

Comment: Check what? You are just repeating what's already in the question. Please provide complete (but minimal) Java code, including import statements.